# Why is .center only working in the y axis for me?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var friendsButton: UIImageView! //Friends Button
    @IBOutlet var circleButton: UIImageView! //Circle Button
    @IBOutlet var profileButton: UIImageView! //Profile Button
    @IBOutlet var whiteBoxSelector: UIImageView! //White Box Selector

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        whiteBoxSelector.center = self.friendsButton.center //line that doesn't seem to run properly
    }
}
```

Once I run this, my `whiteBoxSelector` moves to the friends button, but only in the y axis, and the x position seems to be 0. I haven't set any constrains for the white box and my buttons are in a stack view.

Answer (score 0):

The **center** property of a view specifies:

> The center of the frame.
>  The center is specified within **the coordinate
>   system of its superview** and is measured in points. Setting this
>   property changes the values of the frame properties accordingly.

Your issue is that the `whiteBoxSelector` and `friendsButton` don't share the same `superview`, so the coordinate systems aren't the same.  You need to translate the `center` of the `friendsButton` from the coordinate system of the `friendsButton` (its superview) to the coordinate system of the `whiteBoxSelector` (its superview).

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    whiteBoxSelector.center = whiteBoxSelector.superview.convert(friendsButton.center, from: friendsButton.superview)
}
```